# Conditional compilation for app name

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, conditional-compilation

I have a Windows phone app and 2 different configuration, what I want is to set in a configuration a different display name for the app, there's any automatized way to do this?

I tried modifing the AssemblyTitle attribute in AssemblyInfo.cs but that doesn't do anything

Comment: Might not be the best way, but could you not just store both in the config and choose in code by means of an if statement to choose which one you load into the name?

Comment: @Shane.C Can you write an example I'm not very fond myself of conditional compilation and project configurations

Comment: You can take out core in dll-project and create 2 phone app projects with different configurations and add into them reference on common dll

Comment: @Frank59 I resolve it using a small program fired as a pre build event

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Resolved by creating a small program fired as a Pre-Build event which read the Manifest and change it accordingly to the Config name passed to him

For reference of anyone should have this problem here is the code.
This implementation takes two parameter par1: name of the config par2: path to the WMAppManifest of the application

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        XmlDocument document = GetDocument(args[1]);
        SubstituteName(document, args[0]);
        SaveDocument(document, args[1]);
    }

    private static void SaveDocument(XmlDocument document, string path)
    {
        document.Save(path);
    }

    private static void SubstituteName(XmlDocument document, string ConfigName)
    {
        string name="appname "+ConfigName;
        if (ConfigName.Equals("Config1"))
            name = "appname 1";
        if (ConfigName.Equals("Config2"))
            name = "appname 2";

        XmlNode node = document.SelectSingleNode("//App");
        node.Attributes["Title"].Value = name;
    }

    private static XmlDocument GetDocument(string path)
    {
        XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
        doc.Load(path);
        return doc;
    }
```

to consume in the app project:
In the pre-build event

```
"$(SolutionDir)AppNameChanger.exe" $(ConfigurationName) "$(SolutionDir)WP8Project\Properties\WMAppManifest.xml"
```

Comment: Using the pre-build event is the answer, but creating an application just for that is probably overkill. I would have suggested putting all the manifests in a folder, and copy the appropriate during in the pre-build event.

Comment: @KooKiz the two manifest are the same only the name of the app change, so when I change something in a manifest I want the same change applied to the one with the other name. If I make a copy of them then I have to automatize the process of updating them. Anyway the application is not very complex and was the fastest thing I was able to think.